# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

**i want to copy a folder form path to another but I got this error**

***Error:***

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/compine/data'
```

***code:***

```
import shutil

shutil.copy("D:/compine/data","D:/compine/copy")
```

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to copy entire directory then use

```
shutil.copytree("D:/compine/data","D:/compine/copy")
```

Comment: can you try now

Answer (score 0):

Use `copyfile(source, destination)` instead

Answer (score 0):

`shutil.copytree("D\\compine\\data","D\\compine\\copy")`